# Modules or functions to obtain information from a network interface in Python

Tags: python, networking, interface

I wrote a little application that I use from the terminal in Linux to keep track of the amount of data up and down that I consume in a session of Internet connection (I store the info in MongoDB).  The data up and down I write by hand and read them (visually) from the monitor system, the fact is that I would like to automate more my application and make it read data consumed up and down from the interface network  i use to connect to internet (in my case ppp0), but the detail is in that I does not find the way to do in Python. I guess Python have a module to import or something that lets me do what I want, but until now I have researched I have not found a way to do it.

Do you know of any module, function or similar that allows me to do in python what I want?

any example?

thanks in advance

Comment: This forum thread suggests reading `/proc/net/dev`: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=722781

Comment: See [How can I parse the output of /proc/net/dev into key:value pairs per interface using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052589/how-can-i-parse-the-output-of-proc-net-dev-into-keyvalue-pairs-per-interface-us)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I answer myself

Found in the community PyAr this [recipe](http://python.org.ar/pyar/Recetario/ObtenerBytesTransferidos) to me me like a glove going to do what we wanted without having to use extra commands or other applications.

Slightly modifying the code to better suit my application and add a function that comvierta of bytes to Megabytes leave it like this:

```
def bytestomb(b):
    mb = float(b) / (1024*1024)
    return mb


def bytessubidatransferidos():
    interface= 'ppp0'
    for line in open('/proc/net/dev', 'r'):
        if interface in line:
            data = line.split('%s:' % interface)[1].split()
            tx_bytes =  (data[8])
    return bytestomb(tx_bytes)


def bytesbajadatransferidos():
    interface= 'ppp0'
    for line in open('/proc/net/dev', 'r'):
        if interface in line:
            data = line.split('%s:' % interface)[1].split()
            rx_bytes = (data[0])
    return bytestomb(rx_bytes)


print bytessubidatransferidos()
print bytesbajadatransferidos()
```