# Python writing to a linux /proc/mystats file

Tags: python

Several articles show how to read data from a linux /proc/xxx file, such as: [How can I parse the output of /proc/net/dev into key:value pairs per interface using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052589/how-can-i-parse-the-output-of-proc-net-dev-into-keyvalue-pairs-per-interface-us)

How do I set up a Python application to create and write to my own /proc/mystats file so other processes can monitor it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. `/proc/` is a [special filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) for exposing information the kernel knows about various processes, it's managed by the kernel.

If you want to write running information to a file, use a different directory -- for example, firefox writes stuff into `$HOME/.mozilla`

Comment: Thanks to both Devin & bot403. I'll use named pipe fifo in another folder.

Answer (score 4):

I belive only kernel modules can create entries in a procfs filesystem. Once a kernal module has created an entry it can control the permissions and then you can read/write to it like any file on the filesystem.

However, using procfs is massive overkill if you just want to share data between processes. Have you considered pipes, shared memory, or even just a regular file on the filesystem? There are tons of mechanisms for IPC and you seemed to have picked the most convuluted one.

Answer (score 0):

Infact, you can edit `/proc/xxx` file like normal files but with some limitations. When i was tring to change the conntrack table size i meet the same problem. This is my code and it works fine.

```py
# set totalsize
with open('/proc/.../nf_conntrack_max', 'r+') as f:
    f.write(talbe_size)
    f.close()


# set buckets
with open('/sys/.../hashsize', 'r+') as f:
    f.write(bucket_size)
    f.close()
```