# Firefox/TOR browser automation and bandwidth measurement using Python?

Tags: python, url, firefox, bandwidth, tor

I want to use Python to start and close the TOR browser and have it rebuild circuits, until a certain bandwidth is available:

```
import subprocess

i==0;
while i < 10:
    tor_browser = subprocess.POpen('/usr/share/applications/torbrowser-launcher')
    bw = load_url.measure_bandwidth('https://blah.com/test.png')    #???
    if bw > bw_min:    #e.g. 2 Mbps
        break
    else:
        tor_browser.kill()
        i+=1
```

How can I tell the browser to load a certain URL and get a bandwidth measurement, i.e. the `load_url.measure_bandwidth` part? Does TOR send/receive traffic through a specific TCP port? Does Linux maybe have a built-in feature I could tap into (driver, system service etc.) that already does the part of monitoring bandwidth or network traffic?

Comment: Do you control the measurement endpoint (i.e. the URL)? Do you have a resource that's sufficiently big to be downloaded and potentially reach higher bandwidths? That aside, I'm afraid that while you can open a website from the command line, measuring it would be much harder.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about using a direct download link for a 5-10 MB file e.g. from Dropbox, Google drive or a university file server that offers consistent bandwidths. In any case, the bottleneck is TOR and `bw_min` will in practice be much lower than both the output from the download server and the local ISP connection

Comment: Both the size of the test file and `bw_min` will be adjusted to minimize the time for this startup procedure (e.g. using a 500 MB test file to gauge the speed or setting `bw_min` to 100 Mbps for a standard TOR circuit wouldn't be practical)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may try to use two different strategies here, depending how much control you want on the results of your tests and how much efforts you want to put into your solution :-)

1. If you can tamper with the local TOR installation and allow signed add-ons, you can write a Firefox addon to perform detailed measurements. One similar example can [be found here](https://github.com/Dexterp37/icq-shield-study) (disclaimer: I'm the author). It's pretty old, but high level [this creates a `browser` element](https://github.com/Dexterp37/icq-shield-study/blob/8f5f174a0e0bca5a1486ea08913b3d1cbfcfc2c1/addon/lib/Feature.jsm#L242-L356) and downloads a test file, performing a breakdown of the measures using the [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API).
2. Assuming you are on a Linux machine, you can get the PID of the Firefox process, then query `/proc/{PID}/net/dev` and parse it. I haven't tested this last solution personally, but it seems like it should work and at least give you the number of bytes transferred over a specific interface.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful information. I think I'll pass on writing an add-on, although this might come in handy to do measurements for individual files (not sure if this can be implemented). For now, being on a Linux machine, a terminal query could do the trick. I did `grep /proc/$(pgrep firefox)/net/dev` - what am I looking at here? I.e. from which point in time did the received/transmitted counter start to count? And how can I "read out" one specific value (e.g. only the received Bytes of a certain interface)?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1052628/261698) will show how to parse the pseudofile in Python as a dictionary. Since the measurements are tied to a PID, I would _assume_ they refer to the lifetime of the process itself, i.e. from when it started. Please check this assumption before trusting this data!