# How to calculate internet data usage in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, desktop, scapy

How can I calculate internet data usage in python ?
I tried psutil but i am not really sure how to calculate it
is it write to use psutil and can we use socket or scapy ?

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you want to do? For example - do you want to know how many bytes were sent and recieved by each interface? Is this for a specific OS?

Comment: Yes I want to know that and also to calculate the internet usage for my device like when windows calculate it

Comment: If you are using linux, then this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052589/how-can-i-parse-the-output-of-proc-net-dev-into-keyvalue-pairs-per-interface-u is for you. A quick internet search find this github package - https://gist.github.com/racerxdl/d4b4670d189ad579ae1a

Comment: no actually I'm using windows

Comment: but with python is it different ?

Comment: So you're talking about the amount of data uploaded and downloaded from a specific Wifi connection?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, then the following code will give you what you need-

```py
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)
{'lo': snetio(bytes_sent=547971, bytes_recv=547971, packets_sent=5075, packets_recv=5075, errin=0, errout=0, dropin=0, dropout=0),
'wlan0': snetio(bytes_sent=13921765, bytes_recv=62162574, packets_sent=79097, packets_recv=89648, errin=0, errout=0, dropin=0, dropout=0)}
```

This is copied straight from the [docs](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_io_counters)

The result is the amount of data sent and recieved for each interface. You will have to determine which interface you are interested in, perhaps the interface relevant to you Wifi. What you will probably be most interested in are the `bytes_sent` and `bytes_recv` values.

Comment: with this way can I measure the internet usage ?