# Getting Current internet usage using python

Tags: python

I'm working on an application that keeps an eye on my internet usage and takes action if it detects that my download speed has dropped to zero. Essentially, I want my computer to shut down automatically if it's not downloading anything.

I've looked into using the `speedtest-cli` library, but it seems to only provide the overall speed, not the real-time speed. I need a way to accurately track the current download speed as it fluctuates.

Comment: You might try [pysnmplib](https://pypi.org/project/pysnmplib/) and turning on [windows snmp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/setting-up-the-wmi-snmp-environment). I use pysnmplib to poll my router ports every ten seconds and there are lots of raw packet details you can obtain.

Comment: Are you trying to monitor internet usage or speed? I am not trying to criticize your thought process, but perhaps the issue here is that these are two different things and you are confusing them. Programs that you could write or use to check speed (such as speedtest-cli, speedtest apps etc) measure how fast you could theoretically download or upload with your current bandwidth. Usage would be more how much your computer is actually doing. Which are you looking for?

Comment: I want to monitor current internet usage

Comment: I believe this thread points to a module that would help you. It looks somewhat complex and I don't know much about it, though.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73338436/how-to-calculate-internet-data-usage-in-python 

If you don't want to bother with that, and you live alone, you could actually use a speedtesting program, but it would be kinda jank. Youd have to gather data about how much bandwidth you use for other things on average and then shut your computer off when the available bandwidth exceeds a certain margin. Its easy to code but less efficient and effective.